# Mobilefirst 7.1 - Issue with JAX-ws jars files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I a getting some issues(JVM Verify Error) when using jaxb, Jax-ws jar files in Liberty Core 8.5 (Standalone Test environment) installed with mobilefirst.

But the same thing works very well in Development server.

```
vax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox$2.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:378)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:383)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.accessTheResourceWithIdentity(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.access$000(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.handleRequest(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:83)
[4/19/16 23:56:00:135 EDT] 000001a8 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter 82" at ffdc_16.04.19_23.55.59.0.log
[4/19/16 23:56:00:368 EDT] 000001a8 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter 144" at ffdc_16.04.19_23.56.00.0.log
[4/19/16 23:56:00:386 EDT] 000001a8 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters 1064" at ffdc_16.04.19_23.56.00.1.log
[4/19/16 23:56:00:407 EDT] 000001a8 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox$2.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:378)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:383)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.accessTheResourceWithIdentity(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.access$000(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.handleRequest(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:83)
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox$2.doFilter(JAXRSSandbox.java:378)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSSandbox.handleRequest(JAXRSSandbox.java:383)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/client/WSServiceDelegate, method=createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;, pc=0
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.accessTheResourceWithIdentity(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.access$000(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor$1.run(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.worklight.adapters.rest.JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.handleRequest(JAXRSAdapterRequestInterceptor.java:83)
```

In my server.xml I mapped al the Jar files also  used delegation="parentLast" to makes sure Application JARS are loaded first

```
<application id="MyProject" name="MyProject" location="MyProject.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_MyProject">
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
                   <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="management-api.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="jaxb-api.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="jaxb-core.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="policy.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="jaxws-rt.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="stax-ex.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="gmbal-api-only.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="streambuffer.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="ha-api.jar"/>
                    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MyProject/lib" includes="jaxb-impl.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_*.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

If I am not wrong there is come conflict with the JAR files added with the Application War vs the Jars loaded by liberty core by default  .

I also tried by removing all the JAXB jars from Application.

That actually fixed the problem and I was able to invoke service but when ever there is exception I started getting the below error.

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy36.downloadPDB(Unknown Source)
    at path.to.my.code.downloadInvalidFileID(SingleMethodTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution finally.

I matched my configuration from development environment. The only difference was I did not include these jars in myProject.war/WEB-INF/lib. After adding to that it resolved the issue.

However I am not convinced with the solution because I already had these jars in in shared location and also referred in server.xml. So deploying it with WAR shouldn't be required. But it solved my problem.